# How to attach event to this hyperlink button

Tags: c#, javascript, dom, gridview, webforms

How can I add `onClientClick` event to this

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$m$g_8dbaa58f_d132_4042_b180_3c555d885dde$ctl00$GridView1','Delete$0')">Delete</a>
```

Since it's a commandfield in `Gridview` so I couldn't get it directly, [check this question for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315007/command-field-showing-messagebox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the gridview's RowDataBound event and search for the anchor tag in the item's Controls collection.

```
    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        // this will apply the action in the lambda expression to all controls or sub-controls of the row matching type LinkButton  
        // (you may have a different control type and you may want to alter your lambda expression to check that the control matched is really the control you want to manipulate)
        SearchControls<LinkButton>(e.Row, button => button.OnClientClick = "alert('here');");
    }

    // recursive Control search function
    private void SearchControls<T>(Control start, Action<T> itemMatch)
    {
        foreach (var c in start.Controls.OfType<T>())
            itemMatch(c);

        foreach (var c in start.Controls.OfType<Control>())
            SearchControls<T>(c, itemMatch);
    }
```

Comment: this will add alerts for all the buttons in grid view

Comment: That's the idea - see the comment in OnRowDataBound - up to him to filter as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<a href = "#" onclick="alert('Client click event..!')">Detail</a>
```