# deleting record when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview, webforms

I am trying to show a confirmation box, which works perfectly with `Confirm` but doesn't work with my custom message box,

This works,

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        LinkButton link = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[2];
        if (link != null)
        {
            link.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete?')";
        }
    }
}
```

BUT when i put this instead

```
link.OnClientClick = "ConfirmationBox()";


 function ConfirmationBox() 
    { 
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '275px' } 
    }); 
    }
```

**It shows message box but then it also deleting my record :'(**

Still confused ? check this out,

[Command field showing messagebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16315007/command-field-showing-messagebox)

**Edit**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { 

 $('#yes').click(function() { 
        $.unblockUI(); 
        return true;
    });

    $('#no').click(function() { 
        $.unblockUI(); 
        return false; 
    }); 
}); 
 </script>
```

Comment: What is going on here?

Comment: I call it deep programming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jim said you have to have

```
link.OnClientClick = "return ConfirmationBox()";
```

ConfirmationBox should always return false. You need to have one more button which will perform the delete operation and you need to fire that button's click event if user press yes button. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sir if you've not read my complete answer, then do it first. To make it work you need to do what I said, without that Jim's answer won't solve the problem, that you should have figured out already.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the difference between the two `OnClientClick` events. The one that works properly *returns* a value, whereas the one that does not does not.

When the button is clicked, the button action is performed. The on-click action is also performed. However, if the on-click action returns false, the button's action is cancelled. Change

```
link.OnClientClick = "ConfirmationBox()";
```

to

```
link.OnClientClick = "return ConfirmationBox()";
```

and make `ConfirmationBox()` return false if the action is not confirmed.

Comment: thanks it fixed half of the problem, however I am not able to delete a record now, when I press "yes"

Comment: The key to that is in my last sentence "...make `ConfirmationBox()` return false *if the action is not confirmed*". If the action *is* confirmed, you need to return true.

Comment: action is confirmed or not depends on yes or no, and yes is returning true, but nothing happening afterwards Sir

Comment: Oh, I see your updated code. It's the `ConfirmationBox()` method that needs to return true or false, not the click event of the yes or no button.

Answer (score 1):

The second option most probably does not return `false`, this is why your record is deleted in any case. You can verify it by changing it to :

```
function ConfirmationBox() 
    { 
      $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '275px' }}); 
      return false;
    }
```

Not that this would prevent deleting the record, but also will not let you to delete it. You would need something that would return the result of the UI control.

Also you should modify the link :

```
link.OnClientClick = "return ConfirmationBox()";
```

Comment: I added more code in question, as half of problem is solved, thanks

Comment: Here is a full example that accomplishes exactly what you want with blockUI http://highoncoding.com/Articles/562_GridView_Confirmation_Box_Using_JQuery_BlockUI.aspx

Comment: I already know that way of doing it, but I want to do the way I mentioned above :)

Comment: OK, then you should define #yes and #no divs in your #question div, so that when the question is shown you can then return the result depending on the answer.

Comment: If they are already inside the question div, then you need to provide actual error maybe a firebug output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29248/discussion-between-user13814-and-semihyagcioglu)

Comment: Where are they if they are not in question div sir ?

Comment: Can you update the question with the markup, and also the error messages you get when you click yes or no.

Comment: Try calling $.unblockUI() on an element instead, eg. $('body').unblock();

Comment: what would that going to do ?

Comment: It would unblock the element and hopefully execute the remaining lines, in this case return false or true. You can read more about element blocking here : http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#element